# How to generate xml file from listview?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have a listview which contains data in  `Details` view mode. So now my task is to take back up of data which ever i select from listview and create .xml file.I created a button "Export" and put a code to open "SaveFileDialog" in `export_Click` event handler.Now can anybody provide me the logic to achieve the task to create .xml file from the datas selected from listview in `"export_Click`" eventhandler .
This is the bit of listview code used in the existing application.

```
public class TrevoListView : System.Windows.Forms.ListView, IEditable
public class BaseLVItem : System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
      public TrevoListView ListView
      {
         get{ return t_listView; }
      }
```

If i iterate by using foreach loop , i will get each object like shown below, but i really stuck what logic i can do for creating xml?

```
foreach(BaseLVItem item in ListView.SelectedItems)
```

And one more thing these all datas displayed in listivew are from parent xml files. Server will serialize these xml and send it to GUI for displaying in controls like listview, we also have dataschema "TrevoDataSchema.xsd"
Do i need to use XDocument or any other logic in side `export_Click` event handler ?

Comment: asking for help and assistance to a problem will generate more answers than "please provide code".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write XML file from a ListView in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067027/how-to-write-xml-file-from-a-listview-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XDocument from LINQ to XML and create a XML file from the ListItems, as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4067146/64497

And use

```
XDocument.Save(filename)
```

To save the xml file, `filename` here is the name returned by the `SaveFileDialog`